# Built-in display shown as prime display which cannot be controlled by nvidia-settings

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, 20.04, nvidia-prime

My NVIDIA X server setting on my laptop shows my built in display as primary display which cannot be controlled by NVIDIA-settings and must be configured by an external RandR capable tool. Only a connected external monitor can be changed by the NVIDIA-settings. I have tried many solutions but nothing seems to be working.

PS: My laptop has an Intel and NVIDIA graphics(dedicated graphics)optimus nvidia

Answer (score 0):

There is a command for switching between Intel and NVIDIA graphics called `vgaswitcheroo`. See [this wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics) page for instructions to enable it.

Comment: Well, that's the way it is on most hybrid setups.  The laptops display is always handled by & connected to the iGPU, thru a prime profile you can have the nvidia gpu handle the rendering. A typical hdmi or possibly a displayport external  is connected to the nvidia gpu. So what your seeing is the way it is, period.

Comment: So apparently there isn't any way to run both the GPU simultaneously rather than switching from iGPU to NVIDIA and back. Or is there any other method to get the same?